# DialogFragment : Using AlertDialog with custom layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I'm rewriting my application with `Fragments API` support. In the original application I have an `AlertDialog` that is created like this :

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_dialog, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(view);
    ListView mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.mblist);
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.sysinfo)).setNeutralButton(
            getString(R.string.okay), null);
    Cursor dcursor = propManager.propCursor();
    if (dcursor.moveToFirst()) {
        startManagingCursor(dcursor);
        String[] from = { Constants.NAME_DET,
                Constants.VALUE_DET };
        int[] to = { R.id.mbname, R.id.mbvalue };
        SimpleCursorAdapter dadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.info_list_row, dcursor, from, to);
        mListView.setAdapter(dadapter);
    }
    final Dialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
```

How can I display the same dialog via a DialogFragment? I have read the documentation but have trouble figuring out how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I'm surprised that nobody answered. This is the solution:

```
public class PropDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private PropDialogFragment() { /*empty*/ } 

    /** creates a new instance of PropDialogFragment */
    public static PropDialogFragment newInstance() {
        return new PropDialogFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //getting proper access to LayoutInflater is the trick. getLayoutInflater is a                   //Function
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setView(view);
        builder.setTitle(getActivity().getString(R.string.sysinfo)).setNeutralButton(
                getActivity().getString(R.string.okay), null);
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

You can show the dialog using :

```
private void showDialog() {
    // DialogFragment.show() will take care of adding the fragment
    // in a transaction.  We also want to remove any currently showing
    // dialog, so make our own transaction and take care of that here.
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev);
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    // Create and show the dialog.
    DialogFragment newFragment = PropDialogFragment.newInstance();
    newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
}
```

Comment: Would you rather `getActivity().getLayoutInflater()` instead of calling the system service and casting?

Comment: Awesome answer.  Just in case anyone's curious, [the docs cover this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).

Comment: I thought that ```fragment transactions``` were necessary to show the ```AlertDialog```. But now I am using ```dialog.show();``` directly from a ```DialogFragment``` and it works.

Comment: I know this is old, but fragments can't have private default constructors, because they can be recreated by the system.

Comment: `LayoutInflater.from(getContext())` also seems to work instead of `getActivity().getLayoutInflater()`. Calling `getActivity()` in fragments always makes me nervous!

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can just show your Fragment like this:

```
SherlockDialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
```

And this would be a simple TimePickerFragment:

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}
}
```