# Custom Support Dialog Fragment text is the wrong color

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment, android-support-library

If I put a `TextView` in a custom dialog box, the text will be black by default.

Unfortunately, the support fragment dialogs backgrounds are dark gray. Black on gray is very hard to read.

I could change the `TextView` to white or something like `android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverseDisableOnly"`. 
But the dialog boxes on the new android (Holo Light) are white. So it will be white on white.

I could use a hack like forcing it to be white on old versions of Android and forcing it to be black on newer versions of Android, but I'd rather find a more elegant solution.

Is there a way to change the `TextView` to imitate the same text that's normally put on the support `DialogFragment`? I'm using Action Bar Sherlock, if that matters.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
alertDialogBuilder.setInverseBackgroundForced( true )
```

works fine in my case on pre-Honeycomb devices and newer ones.  The title still appears in a darker color but the main text is clearly readable on all devices.

Comment: This question was a long time ago and I can't really remember what I tried to do with it. So it might be a while before I could test this answer :)

Comment: This works for me. This function inverses the background color on old devices while has no effect on newer devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ActionBarSherlock, I'm guessing you're supporting old devices as well. Sad thing about it is that old phones won't display any Holo Dialog, only old ugly Dialogs (and on many phones, they'll also be heavily customized by manufacturer). Therefore can't assume your Dialog will be Light.

There's only 2 things you can do :

- Leave it as is and let the system handle the style of your Dialog
- Set a custom view to your Dialog. Check here :
  [DialogFragment : Using AlertDialog with custom layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579545/dialogfragment-using-alertdialog-with-custom-layout)

Comment: I'm already using a custom dialog. It looks just fine on the boring old compatibility dialogs, but looks wrong on the custom ones. Changing the background is a possibility, but then I'd have to switch all the existing dialogs to have a custom background.