# StackOverflowError when trying to inflate a custom layout for an AlertDialog inside a DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to create an AlertDialog, by using the Builder and setting a custom view. When I try to inflate the view inside of onCreateDialog, I get a StackOverflowError..

Here is the code up to the point where it loops back to onCreateDialog:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.enter_time);

    LinearLayout outerLayout = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState)
            .inflate(R.layout.time_entry_dialog, null);
    ...
}
```

And here is the LogCat output:

```
02-28 22:30:04.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4250): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 22:30:04.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4250): java.lang.StackOverflowError
02-28 22:30:04.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4250):     at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4009)
02-28 22:30:04.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4250):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:210)
02-28 22:30:04.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4250):     at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getSystemService(ContextThemeWrapper.java:75)
02-28 22:30:04.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4250):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams.<init>(AlertController.java:812)
02-28 22:30:04.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4250):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:374)
02-28 22:30:04.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4250):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:359)
02-28 22:30:04.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4250):     at com.sweatyreptile.chee.runtimetracker.TimeEntryDialogFragment.onCreateDialog(TimeEntryDialogFragment.java:18)
02-28 22:30:04.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4250):     at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:295)
02-28 22:30:04.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4250):     at com.sweatyreptile.chee.runtimetracker.TimeEntryDialogFragment.onCreateDialog(TimeEntryDialogFragment.java:21)
02-28 22:30:04.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4250):     at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:295)
02-28 22:30:04.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4250):     at com.sweatyreptile.chee.runtimetracker.TimeEntryDialogFragment.onCreateDialog(TimeEntryDialogFragment.java:21)
02-28 22:30:04.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4250):     at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:295)
...etc
```

**EDIT:** I found this line in the source of [DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/app/DialogFragment.java#DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater%28android.os.Bundle%29):

```
mDialog = onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
```

So.. if I can't get a LayoutInflator inside of onCreateDialog without causing infinite recursion, how do I inflate a view for a custom AlertDialog?

Comment: What do you have in the `time_entry_dialog`? Also don't be afraid to post the stacktrace with the exception.

Comment: Please add your Logcat output

Comment: I added the LogCat output.

@Luksprog, `time_entry_dialog` is just a LinearLayout with centered gravity

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If found the problem. [DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/app/DialogFragment.java#DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater%28android.os.Bundle%29) contains a call to `onCreateDialog()`, so calling `onCreateDialog()` from within `getLayoutInflater()` creates an infinite loop.

I found the solution in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10585164/2020340

I'm not exactly sure if this is good form, because it doesn't really seem like it, but I replaced

```
getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState)
```

with

```
getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

**Edit:** They are the same. See this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20995083/2020340

Comment: Is that an Android bug? I had this problem too, and to me calling onCreateDialog from within getLayoutInflater doesn't make sense?

Comment: `LayoutInflater.from(getContext())` seems to work as well.

Comment: `getActivity().getLayoutInflater()` also works, although you should also check for `getActivity()` returning `null` if you're using a v4 support library Fragment. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()

Comment: Disappointing that 5 years later, the Android docs still guide people to use the _**wrong**_ method: `layoutInflater.inflate(...)` https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#kotlin

Comment: Both LayoutInflater.from(getContext()) and getActivity().getLayoutInflater() are working.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is fixed in Fragment 1.2.3: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.2.3.

The docs do use `requireActivity().getLayoutInflater()` rather than just `getLayoutInflater` however so it still might not be recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `LayoutInflater.from(getContext())`.

If you are using `viewbindings` you can call it like this:

`binding = FragmentOtpDialogBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()));`