# AlertDialog.Builder.setView causes StackOverflowError

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dialog, stack-overflow

I'm trying to show a dialog with custom view but I'm facing `java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB` and I don't know how to handle it. 
Here is my code. Any help is appreciated.

DialogFragment:

```
class MyDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return activity?.let {
            AlertDialog.Builder(it)
                .setView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null))
                .create()
            }
    } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
}
```

custom_dialog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151783/stackoverflowerror-when-trying-to-inflate-a-custom-layout-for-an-alertdialog-ins

Comment: @ivkil thanks the link solved the problem