# Can't create a new custom dialog

Tags: java, android

I can't create new custom dialog like in most tutorials.

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle("hi")
                .setMessage("hello")
                .setNeutralButton("ok", null)
                .create();
    }
}
```

and now I'm trying create a new object:

```
DialogFragment dialog = new MyDialog();
```

Android studio show me:

> required DialogFragment, found MyDialog

How to fix it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579545/dialogfragment-using-alertdialog-with-custom-layout

Comment: can you show design of dialog that you want to implement?

Comment: I want only that was i wrote, dont have layout, my problem is can't create a new object

Comment: Can you show following line code after this line `DialogFragment dialog = new MyDialog();`?

Answer (score 1):

I use this to create a true custom dialog box.

This requires a layout called *alert_dialog_view*

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
View alertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_view, null);

//Set the view
alert.setView(alertView);
//Show alert
final AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.show();
//OPTIONAL Can not close the alert by touching outside.
alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

To create a standard dialog box, you can do this...

```
public class DialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
   @Override
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
      builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            toast.makeText(this,"enter a text here",Toast.LENTH_SHORT).show();
         }
      })
      .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            finish();
         });
         // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
         return builder.create();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: this is not the answer, my problem is can't create object

Comment: if this isnt the answer then you do not want to create a "custom" dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried as follow to create a custom dialog:

1. Create XML file `dialog.xml` in folder `layout` to set layout and views for your dialog layout
2. In your activity file:

   ```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(YourActivity.this);
    dialog.setTitle("Your dialog title");
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    dialog.show();
   ```
3. set on click for the views inside your dialog, example:

   ```
    Button btn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_id);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View view) 
      {
        //Insert your code here
      }
    });
   ```